# Two plugin.xml files in Mavenized eclipse rcp project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Hi iam working on an rcp project , i have a folder in my eclipse project 
src/main/resources

This folder has plugin.xml , however there is another plugin.xml in the main project folder . I want to know what is the difference between the two plugin.xml files .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> The plug-in manifest file, plugin.xml, describes how the plug-in extends the platform, what extensions it publishes itself, and how it implements its functionality.

[src](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_What_is_the_plug-in_manifest_file_(plugin.xml)%3F)

See which one is included in your build configuration :
seek `bin.includes` in your `build.properties` file

There might be one of the two which is deprecated or has nothing to do with the plugin

Comment: i can t find build.properties file can you let me know where i can find it , i can see a bundle.properties file

Comment: search in your workspace for `plugin.xml` occurence and see which one is used